# Passing a value from ftl page to servlet controller

Tags: java, spring, servlets, html

I am totally new in servlet and FreeMarker (.ftl) templates hence some amount of guesswork is involved here. The problem is that I have to send one value from the web page that I have to receive in my servlet.

Here is my efforts in doing so

**FTL code:**

```
<form action="someAcction.spring" method="post">
    <input type = "submit" value="Generate Values">
    <input type = "text" placeholder = "Some long value">
    <input type = submit name="someValue" value=${someValue}>
</form>
```

**Controller Code:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someAction")
@ResponseBody
String generateSomeValues(@ModelAttribute("someValue") String someValueStr) {
    Long someValue;
    try{
            someValue = Long.parseLong(someValueStr.trim());
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
         return "Invalid some value " + someValueStr;

    //...... Some more code
}
```

Please point me, what is wrong in here.

Comment: input type of "someValue" is incorrect. I think it should be text instead of submit.

Comment: Problem seemingly is at last line form line. But even after i changed submit to text.... things didnt improve.

Answer (score 0):

If your using AJAX to call this method then supposed to @ResponseBody use. And @ModelAttribute used in case where you are binding object with jstl  tag. In case you are passing value using url appender then it accessed in controller with @RequestParam or @PathVariable.

Try this:

```
<form action="someAcction.spring" method="post">
<input type = "submit" value="Generate Values" name="value1"/>
<input type = "text" placeholder = "Some long value" name="value2"/>
<input type = "submit" name="someValue" value=${someValue}/>
</form>

@RequestMapping(value = "/someAction")
String generateSomeValues(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
  Long someValue;
try{
        someValue = Long.parseLong(request.getParamter("value1"));
        System.out.println(someValue);
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
     return "Invalid some value " + someValueStr;

//...... Some more code
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. though thanks for explaining usage of ResponseBody and ModelAttribute. How framework will know that 'value1' will have respective value. FTL doesn't make those things clear here. Is in't it?

Comment: request object contains the all page data. We retrieve that using  request.getParamter("value1");... by the way which error u got when above code executed ?